# Google sheet text formula not working; query by date and text() not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So I am trying to pull a query by date, but when I do exactly like the tutorials I found on the internet it just doesn't work,

i.e. :

```
=QUERY(Penjualan!$A$1:$H$136,"select A , B , D , H where B > date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

or

```
=QUERY(Penjualan!A1:H; "select A , B , D , H where B = date '"&text(D1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'" )
```

does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Google sheets is not Excel.  Please read the tag descriptions before using them

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(); "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

---

```
=QUERY(Penjualan!A1:H; 
 "select A,B,D,H where B = date '"&TEXT(D1; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

---

```
=QUERY(Penjualan!A1:H; 
 "select A,B,D,H where B > date '"&TEXT(TODAY(); "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 1)
```

Comment: it works! wow I didn't think of changing the comma to semi colon, thank you